# In MS Studio how to SELECT from an existing SQL file

Tags: query, subquery, datafile

I have a complicated query that select parts from an MRP  table using several different criteria.  The output of the query is a list of parts which includes the key field [PartNum].  I have saved this query to a file, for example let's says "MyQuery.sql".

I want to use the output of that query in another query, something like "SELECT * FROM [MyQuery] JOIN [part_stock] on [part_stock].[PartNum] = [MyQuery].[PartNum]".  The idea is that I have this rather complicated selection criteria for extracting a list of parts from the database.  I then want to run other queries on just those selected part numbers.  I could just copy all the statements from the original query into the new queries, but that would make them overly complicated.  Also, I may want to change the selection criteria for the parts, and I would prefer to only change it in one file and then just re-execute all the queries that use that list.

I realize that I could use the first query to create a table in the DB, and then have the other queries reference that table.  But this is a live MPR system and I don't want to alter the DB schema (especially since I don't have much experience with SQL).

How can I use the output from one query file as the input to another query?  If that's not possible, is there another way to accomplish this task without creating a table in the DB?

Comment: Generally to consume the results of a SQL query in another query, one references that query (either directly or indirectly). The script file is just a way to save the query for adhoc use later on. But if you wanted to consume the results more naturally you'd generally want to create the appropriate object that contains that query (e.g. a stored procedure or view) and then your other queries can reference that object without you having to repeat code with the query it contains. If you can't create any objects in the MRP database though, are you able to create a separate database to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

I do that a lot.

Yes I have my library of scripts,
for instance, to check if the replication is healthy,

but it could also be just a query.

the way I do is - I use powershell.

basically this shows me all the scripts that are on a folder:

first you copy your file `MyQuery.sql` into this folder:
`C:\Users\My_name\OneDrive\scripts to add to repository\`

this script will list all files in that folder:

```
  $path = "C:\Users\My_name\OneDrive\scripts to add to repository\"
  $sqlScripts = get-childItem -path $path
  $sqlScripts  

  foreach ($SQL in $sqlScripts){
    Write-Host $path$SQL

  }
```

to run a script I use the following command:

```
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $SQLConn  -File "C:\Users\My_name\OneDrive\scripts to add to repository\scripts to add to repository\MyQuery.sql"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm very new to SQL Studio.  I follow the basic idea of your script, but I'm not clear on what happens afterwards.  I think you're telling me how to save the query in the database just as I would a table, correct?  I mentioned that I would rather not modify the schema, but that's just because I don't have a good understanding of how the DB is organized and so it's difficult for me to assess the risks of adding a table (or query).

Comment: That being said, I have added several user defined functions with very customized names to keep them well separated from the rest of the MRP system.  So I don't mind adding a table (or query) as long a I understand what I'm doing and what impact it might have.